# Issue with VBA Excel retrieve data from IBM Personal Communications (PCOMM) in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, excel, settext, vba

i'm trying to write a macro in Excel that can help me send inputs to PCOMM and retrieve the data from there. My codes work perfectly when i test it on Windows XP. However, when i run them on Windows 7, it doesn't run and just freezes. Below is a sample:

```
Dim autECLPSObj As Object

Dim autECLConnList As Object

Set autECLPSObj = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLPS")

Set autECLConnList = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLConnList")

' Initialize the connection

autECLConnList.Refresh

autECLPSObj.SetConnectionByHandle (autECLConnList(1).Handle)

autECLPSObj.SetText "test", 24, 11
```

So basically when i try to debug on Windows 7 (and move each line using F8), it passes up to "SetText" line and then it just freezes - the Excel keeps showing that its "running" while nothing was input into PCOMM.

Updates: Try to run using different Windows and PComm versions. Here are summaries:
* Win XP + PComm 5.7/5.9/6.0: codes worked
* Win 7 + PComm 5.7/5.9: codes worked
* Win 7 + PComm 6.0: codes NOT work

Any ideas?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Do you have the same drivers on both machines?

Comment: After trying the same codes on different computer builds and different pcomm versions, i found out that the codes only have issues when running on Win 7 with PComm 6.0. The codes work fine when running on Win XP + PComm 6.0/5.9/5.7 and work fine when running on Win 7 + PComm 5.9. So not sure why it doesn't work with Win 7 + PComm 6.0...

Answer (score 1):

normally I use SendKeys to input something in PCOMM.

autECLPSObj.SendKeys "xxx", 24, 11